# How to place myapp in Applications location developed through py2app on mac osx

Tags: python, macos, py2app

I had developed an app in python on mac osx for opening different file types on double-clicking any file. Then I converted into app by using `py2app`. py2app creates a `myapp.app` within dist folder. I moved myapp.app from dist folder to Applications location. Now, I am able to open any file through myapp just by double-clicking on it. Now, `I want to make it work in such a way that, I don't need to drag and drop myapp to Applications location,`it should automatically install on system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use packagemaker. It makes myapp.pkg file that when double-clicked installa an app in Applications location.

Answer (score 0):

py2app has a "--dist-dir" option for selecting the output directory (default is "diet"). That said, I have never tested using that option for installation in a directory containing other programs and don't know if "python setup.py py2app --dist-dir=/Applications" is save to use.

The alternative is to use a script that copies the application to /Applications (a simple python script, a shell script, or even a distutils command in your setup.py file that invokes py2app and then copies the resulting application to the right location).

Comment: How, it will work if I give my dist to other users. How he wil do it

Comment: Users can install the application just like they install any other app, they drag it to the applications folder.  You could add code to your application that detects if the application is not in the applications folder and offer to copy it for them, but that’s not something py2app can do for you.